# Using python from a specific virtual environment in stata?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, stata, python-venv

Hello everyone I am trying to execute some Python code in a project where most of the code is in Stata. The project has its own virtual environment where I installed only the Python packages I really needed. Is there a way to activate such virtual environment from Stata in order to be able to run through Stata the Python code I wrote?
Thank you

Comment: See https://blog.stata.com/2020/08/18/stata-python-integration-part-1-setting-up-stata-to-use-python/

Answer (score 1):

You tell Stata which Python executable to run at the beginning of your do-file with `python set exec [path]` where `[path]` is the path to the Python executable inside your particular environment.

For example it might look something like this:

```
python set exec "C:\Users\guido\anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe"
```

if your environment was called `myenv`.

IIRC Stata won't let you re-set the Python location once Python is initialized and so the above spits out an error if you re-run without re-starting, so to get around that you could do something like this:

```
* Set python executable to virtual environment unless already initialized in correct location)

local pypath C:\Users\guido\anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe

python query
if r(initialized) == 1 {
    assert "`r(execpath)'" == "`pypath'"
}
else {
    python set exec "`pypath'"
}
```

Comment: Hi @joshb thanks a lot for yor answer. My issue is that these are virtual environment, so I don't really have an executable of python in the folder (to the best of my understanding). p.s. I am working in OS environment.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I've only used Anaconda environments and assumed you were talking about that. Sorry, if there isn't an executable I'm not sure how one does this. You might consider asking at https://www.statalist.org/forums/ (mention that you've cross-posted here) which is a much more active forum for Stata questions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help anyways!
Guido